# Loading GMM models in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am building up a speaker recognization app, while loading gmm models, I am getting such an error.

```
models = [pickle.load(open(fname,'r')) for fname in gmmFiles]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How can I fix it?

```
path = "speaker_models/"

gmmFiles = [os.path.join(path ,fname) for fname in 
              os.listdir(path) if name.endswith('.gmm')]


models = [pickle.load(open(fname,'r')) for fname in gmmFiles]
```

Comment: As I understand it a GMM file is an XML-formatted text file used to create .BMG files.  Have you previously pickled the gmm file, if you have what code was used for that process?  If you haven't, what makes you think you can use picle to open the file?

Comment: I have not pickled the gmm files, what do you recommend opening them?

Comment: something that opens xml files